# How to control the test flow

Tags: pytest

I have a test campaign which contains tests of 1,2,3,4,5,6 and I'd like to control the execution flow in one test run. For example, after running tests 1, 2, 3, I need to perform some test setups before executing 4,5,6. Is there any feature or plugin in pytest support this. Also, I don't want to group the tests into multiple test runs.

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` runs tests in the order that they appear in a module. So if tests 1, 2 and 3 are defined before 4, 5 and 6 in the module they would get executed first. But, in case they are not, or if they are in different modules or you just want to ensure some order, you should check this plugin: [pytest-ordering](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Note that there are other alternatives also, if you don't want to use this plugin e.g. [pytest_collection_modifyitems](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook, which lets you re-order collected tests in place.

For the part where you want to do some test setups before executing test 4, 5 and 6, you can use pytest [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html). For your case, you can define a session scoped fixture which does the setup job and then include this fixture in the argument list of the tests. Something like below:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_setup():
    print ("Setup done")

def test_1():
    assert True
def test_2():
    assert True
def test_3(test_setup):
    assert True
def test_4(test_setup):
    assert True
```

Here, `test_1` and `test_2` would get executed first. Then `test_setup` would be invoked followed up by `test_3` and `test_4`.